# Javascript function not returning a value back to main()

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

Here is a snippet of my codes. It's on Google Apps Script, although I don't think that would matter in this case.

```
function main() {
  ....
  setUpCalendar(startDate, endDate, eventIDfromSS, calendarEventID);
  Logger.log("After: " + calendarEventID);
}

function setupCalendar(startDate, endDate, eventIDfromSS, calendarEventID) {
  ...
  calendarEventID = event.getId();
  Logger.log("Before: " + calendarEventID);
  return calendarEventID;    
}
```

I'm not sure how to return the value of calendarEventID back to my main() function.

Comment: I think you need to change the second to last line in your main function to `var calendarEventID = setUpCalendar(startDate, endDate, eventIDfromSS, calendarEventID);`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious or misinterpreting this question:

```
function main() {
  ....
  var calendarEventID = setUpCalendar(startDate, endDate, eventIDfromSS, calendarEventID);
  Logger.log("After: " + calendarEventID);
}
```

Comment: Sry, it works. I delete my comment. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your setupCalendar method returns the value to the main method. You need to store it in a variable like returnedValue = setUpCalendar(startDate, endDate, eventIDfromSS, calendarEventID);

So your main function will be like this

```html
function main() {

  ....
  returnedValue = setUpCalendar(startDate, endDate, eventIDfromSS, calendarEventID);
  Logger.log("After: " + calendarEventID);
}
```